# I keep getting "Path must be a string of buffer" error when I try to execute my code through cmd in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, path

What I'm trying to do is to read the files in the file "botimages" using klaw and randomly select one. Here's my code for this:

```
const items = [] 
klaw(__dirname, '../botimages/')
  .on('readable', function () {
    let item
    while ((item = this.read())) {
      items.push(item.path)
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => console.dir(items))


indextodisplay = Math.random()*60; //because there are 60 images in the file
item = items[indextodisplay];
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic async issue.  Since the `.on()` event handlers are asynchronous and are called sometime in the future, the only place you can use the result is inside the `end` event handler:

```
const items = [] 
klaw(__dirname, '../botimages/').on('readable', function () {
    let item;
    while ((item = this.read())) {
      items.push(item.path)
    }
  }).on('end', () => {
      console.dir(items);
      // use items here
      let indextodisplay = Math.random()*60; //because there are 60 images in the file
      let item = items[indextodisplay];
      // now use item here
  });
```

Comment: @BikemB.Ozaydin - Please provide some feedback on this answer.  It appears you asked a question and just dropped off the face of the earth.  That's not how this place works.  When people answer, you should provide some sort of feedback on at least some of the answers to let people know if they've answered your question or not.  Or, if one of the answers gives you what you needed, you can just "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.